# Solving linear equations using Z3

Tags: python, z3py

I have the following linear equations.

```
m = 2 ** 31 - 1

(207560540 ∗ a + b) modulo m = 956631177
(956631177 ∗ a + b) modulo m = 2037688522
```

What is the most efficient way to solve these equations?

I used Z3 however it did not find any solution. My code for Z3 to solve the above equations is:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

from z3 import *

a = Int('a')
b = Int('b')

s = Solver()

s.add((a * 207560540 + b) % 2147483647 == 956631177)
s.add((a * 956631177 + b) % 2147483647 == 2037688522)

print s.check()
print s.model()
```

I know that the solution is: a = 16807, b = 78125, however, how can I make Z3 solve it?

The other method I tried is by setting a and b to BitVec() instead of Integers as shown below:

```
a = BitVec('a', 32)
b = BitVec('b', 32)
```

This gives me an incorrect solution as shown below:

```
[b = 3637638538, a = 4177905984]
```

Is there way to solve it with Z3?

Thanks.

Comment: Dropping in very late, and I suspect the answer given already is the one you needed, but I want to really clarify that your two forms aren't equivalent for 3 reasons:

1. the modulo operator doesn't behave the same as bit truncation (always wraps to 0 and negative numbers always give negative modulus, whereas for signed int positive wraps to negative) modulo;

2. 2147483647 is off-by-one: if you want to wrap like truncation to 31 bits, you want 2147483648;

3. The BitVec is initialized to 32 bits, which would be equivalent to (positive) modulo 4294967296 -- I think you wanted 31 bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An aside on bit-vectors: When you use bit-vectors, then all operations are done modulo `2^N` where `N` is the bit-vector size. So, z3 isn't giving you an `incorrect` solution: If you do the math modulo `2^32`, you'll find that the model it finds is indeed correct.

It appears your problem does indeed need unbounded integers, and it is not really linear due to modulus `2^31-1`. (Linear means multiplication by a constant; modulus by a constant takes you to a different realm.)  And modulus is just not easy to reason with; I don't think z3 is the right tool for this sort of problem, nor any other SMT solver. Tools like mathematica, wolfram-alpha etc. probably are better choices in this case; for instance, see: [wolfram-alpha solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(207560540%20%E2%88%97%20a%20%2B%20b)%20modulo%20m%20%3D%20956631177%20%26%26%20(956631177%20%E2%88%97%20a%20%2B%20b)%20modulo%20m%20%3D%202037688522%20%26%26%20m%20%3D%202%20**%2031%20-%201)